# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializer Error, Please explain

Tags: javascript, eclipse, runtime-error, lwjgl

This Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.level.WoRe.<init>(WoRe.java:46)
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.CaveWorld.start(CaveWorld.java:80)
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.CaveWorld.main(CaveWorld.java:303)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: !!
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.Tea.loT(Tea.java:61)
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.level.Ch.<clinit>(Ch.java:20)
    ... 3 more
```

This is the area of code that is causing this error:

```
  @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
private static HashMap<String, Integer> iM = new HashMap();
  private static int lId = -9999999;

  public static int loT(String path, int m) {
      File file = new File(path);
    try {
      if (iM.containsKey(file)) {
        return ((Integer)iM.get(file)).intValue();
      }
      IntBuffer ib = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);

      GL11.glGenTextures(ib);
      int id = ib.get(0);

      bind(id);

      GL11.glTexParameteri(3553, 10241, m);
      GL11.glTexParameteri(3553, 10240, m);

      BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(file);
      int w = bi.getWidth();
      int h = bi.getHeight();

      ByteBuffer ppi = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(w * h * 4);
      int[] rPs = new int[w * h];
      bi.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, rPs, 0, w);
      for (int i = 0; i < rPs.length; i++)
      {
        int a = rPs[i] >> 24 & 0xFF;
        int r = rPs[i] >> 16 & 0xFF;
        int g = rPs[i] >> 8 & 0xFF;
        int b = rPs[i] & 0xFF;

        rPs[i] = (a << 24 | b << 16 | g << 8 | r);
      }
      ppi.asIntBuffer().put(rPs);
      GLU.gluBuild2DMipmaps(3553, 6408, w, h, 6408, 5121, ppi);

      return id;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException("!!");
    }
  }
```

And more specifically, these exact lines;

```
catch (IOException e)
{
  throw new RuntimeException("!!");
}
```

I have tried removing the throw new RuntimeException but then Eclipse tells me that public static loT needs a return statement although when I keep this line of code in my class file I keep getting this error and my program will just crash.

I am using LWJGL in Eclipse. This class is trying to load a texture file to be assigned to certain things.

I would like to know what is happening, why it is happening, if someone knows how to fix this, and if it can be fixed. If you need more information or it is (for some reason) unclear what I am asking, just post a comment instead of downvoting this because I would really like a fix to this.

Thanks!

EDIT: Thats to @RobHruska and @dhamibirendra for the  original suggestion on using e.printStackTrace().

Here is the updated error log:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.Tea.loT(Tea.java:38)
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.level.Ch.<clinit>(Ch.java:20)
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.level.WoRe.<init>(WoRe.java:46)
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.CaveWorld.start(CaveWorld.java:80)
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.CaveWorld.main(CaveWorld.java:303)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.level.WoRe.<init>(WoRe.java:46)
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.CaveWorld.start(CaveWorld.java:80)
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.CaveWorld.main(CaveWorld.java:303)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.Tea.loT(Tea.java:62)
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.level.Ch.<clinit>(Ch.java:20)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.Tea.loT(Tea.java:38)
    ... 4 more
```

Apparently it is not reading my picture file.

Here is the line requesting it (I believe):

```
private void rebuild(int l) {
    if (rTF == 2) {
      return;
    }
    this.m = false;

    u += 1;

    rTF += 1;

    GL11.glNewList(this.l + l, 4864);
    GL11.glEnable(3553);
    GL11.glBindTexture(3553, tex);
    teb.init();
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
int tiles = 0;
    for (int x = this.x0; x < this.x1; x++) {
      for (int y = this.y0; y < this.y1; y++) {
        for (int z = this.z0; z < this.z1; z++) {
          if (this.wo.isT(x, y, z)) {
            int tex = y == this.wo.d * 2 / 3 ? 0 : 1;
            tiles++;
            if (tex == 0) {
              Ti.stone.render(teb, this.wo, l, x, y, z);
            }else{
              Ti.grass.render(teb, this.wo, l, x, y, z);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    teb.flush();
    GL11.glDisable(3553);
    GL11.glEndList();
  }
```

The int is "tex" and here it is:

```
private static int tex = Tea.loT("groundtex.png", 9728);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the actual `IOException`?

Comment: If you write `throw new RuntimeException(e);`, you'll get a more useful stack trace.

Comment: Make sure that the file path that you pass into this method matches where the file actually is.

Comment: @RobHruska Thanks for the suggestion! an updated error log has been edited into my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code (throw exception part) should be working fine as expected. **ExceptionInInitializer** signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initialize.

It meanse, you are getting some issue at
com.PoseidonTechnologies.caveworld.Tea.loT(Tea.java:61).

Check what's on that line. You are having trouble at there.  Try:

```
catch (IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
  throw new RuntimeException("!!");
}
```

Comment: `Tea.java:61` is going to be `throw new RuntimeException("!!");` in his code.

Comment: check my updated answer, print the stacktrace. Definitely the issue is while reading the file

Comment: I printed the stack trace and I posted the updated error log.

Comment: Well I figured it out but since I cant write my own answer because of stupid reputation I guess I will have to mark this answer as correct. The real problem was that I forgot to call to code to realize that the "groundtex.png" file was in the "src" folder so I needed to add a "src/" to the beginning of my file name. Thanks for all of your help guys!